# react canvas reference to blob?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, blob

So I want a canvas element as a blob in react, to print it with a local printer. Don't mind all the printer logic please. It successfully prints the canvas as a react element, so I would not assume it would have anything to do with the canvas itself.

```js
export const barcode = (props) => {

const canvasReference = useRef(null)
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  //creates the canvas with content
  bwipjs.toCanvas('barcode', ...)
  setLoaded(true)
}

if(setLoaded) {
  window.Printer.init(
    (printer) => { 
      canvasReference.toBlob((blob) => { // <-- FAILS
         printer.printBlob(
           blob,  
           (msg) => {
             console.log('yay')  
           },
           (error) => {
             console.error(error)  
           }
            
         }
      }
    }, 
    (error) => { 
      console.error(error)
    }
}
return <canvas ref={canvasReference} id="barcode" />
}
```

```
TypeError: canvasReference.toBlob is not a function
```

If I try to get the properties of the `canvasReference`, it confirms that it does not have the equievelant of the `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob.

How can I get my canvas as a blob with react?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference of a `useRef` hook is stored in the `current` property.

```
canvasReference.current.toBlob()
```

Comment: yes it does, my bad. I tried to use it before the reference were created. I will mark as answer when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to access `.current` to access the DOM node. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs